# Renaming default id column in Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have an existing application written in Django and I am taking advantage of the models, migrations orm etc.

Each model has a column `id` I was wondering if it is possible to rename this column to something else like `person_id`

I saw some examples creating new primary key columns but that is not what i want. I want to **rename** the existing `id` column name

Comment: No I am not talking about my own created fields I am talking about the auto generated id. I am using the latest django (1.9) and when you create a model via manage.py it doesn't even create a column name like you mention `<model_name>_id` it creates just `id` - no prefix of the model name.

Comment: If I understand you correctly - you are saying when you create a simple model like this `class Person(model.Model): name = models.CharField(max_length100)` You are saying in the person table will have 2 columns looking like this -> `person_id` and `name`

Comment: In my table Person the column names are these -> `id` and `name`

Comment: I think I confused myself about what you were talking about (the above is mainly about foreign keys and I probably will delete comments). But even so, What is the exact problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've said its not what you want but the answer *is* to make your own primary key,

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields),

> If you’d like to specify a custom primary key, just specify primary_key=True on one of your fields. **If Django sees you’ve explicitly set Field.primary_key, it won’t add the automatic id column**.

Since it doesn't add the automatic id column, you've effectively renamed it